# Reasons for a voltage follower introducing voltage gain?

Tags: current, voltage

I'm using a 3130 op-amp as a voltage follower (unity gain buffer amplifier).  However it is introducing voltage gain.

It is wired the following way:

[image: Circuit Schematic]

This is then just fed into a simple low pass RC circuit (R= 2k-10kΩ, C=0.5 μF).

With +Vcc @ +12V and -Vcc @ -12V, I get the following:

Vin ~ -0.4 VDC, Vout ~ 8 VDC

With +Vcc @ +5V and -Vcc @ -5V, I get the following:

Vin ~ -0.4 VDC, Vout ~ 3 VDC

What can cause voltage gain when using an op-amp as a voltage follower?

------------Edit 17-7-15---------------------

I tried a 741 op amp wired the same as above which is unity gain stable and I am still noticing a small voltage gain when supply voltage is +/-5V.  input is -0.41V and output is +1.04V.  However when supply voltage is +/- 12V there is no voltage gain.  I dont see how this can occur, as the 741 op amp is supposed to be unity gain stable.

Comment: Your feedback loop is open or you have mixed up the + and - terminals.  The output is saturating (the output can only reach within 2-3V of the rails, so you're sitting there instead of amplifying.  One way to prove that is to linearly decrease your input voltage- Does the output follow, or stay where it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amplifier CA3130 is NOT unity gain stable. That means: For 100% feedback the unit will oscillate - mostly with amplitudes reachning the power rails. Follow the data sheet recommendations and use a compensation capacitor (>47 pF).

Comment: Is the compensator capacitor between pins 1 and 8?  Also do I need to add a capacitor and resistor to the negative feedback as in the data sheet?

Comment: @gline The best would be to get an op-amp that is stable at unity gain. There are tons of them.

Comment: Ok I'll try, but I'm really using what I have available to me where I am.   Also this op amp was chosen for its relatively high output current (45mA).  I tried a 741 op amp (20mA) and it did not provide as favorable result as the CA3130.

Comment: A compensation capacitor (47...100 pF) between pin 1 and pin 8 should suffice.

Comment: Tried with the LM741 op amp again, it is showing voltage gain also.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few problems. The first is that you have not read the data sheet (or if you have, you did not understand/follow it). The maximum power supply voltage range is 16 volts total. So your +/- 12 volt supplies very likely damaged the chip. No more than +/- 8 volts is allowed.

Now, let's say you've got a new chip and you're running on +/- 5 volts. Where (exactly) are you connecting - input voltage and the - output voltage. I suspect that you are just letting them float, and that will not do. You must connect your input voltage reference to the power supply common, and measure your output voltage with respect to that common as well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkosj8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You are correct, I did not fully understand the data sheet.  I am VERY new to electronics, i must have read it as +/- 16V. The input reference is connected to a common ground, the output is connected to an analogue to digital device which is also connected to the ground, along with the ground of the RC circuit.  So it should act the same as your diagram above.